# Strange output when examing variables with LLDB

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code, lldb

I am debugging the Parity Ethereum client with LLDB in VSCode and I am trying to access a value through several references.

Here is the code with relevant parts only (full code [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/ethcore/transaction/src/transaction.rs))

```
pub struct SignedTransaction {
    transaction: UnverifiedTransaction,
    sender: Address,
    public: Option<Public>,
}

impl Deref for SignedTransaction {
    type Target = UnverifiedTransaction;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.transaction
    }
}

pub struct UnverifiedTransaction {
    unsigned: Transaction,
    v: u64,
    r: U256,
    s: U256,
    hash: H256,
}

impl Deref for UnverifiedTransaction {
    type Target = Transaction;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.unsigned
    }
}

pub struct Transaction {
    pub nonce: U256,
    pub gas_price: U256,
    pub gas: U256,
    pub action: Action,
    pub value: U256,
    pub data: Bytes,
}

pub enum Action {
    Create,
    Call(Address),
}
```

---

I have `&SignedTransaction t` with a value `t.action = Action::Create` (verified by manual print).

I am looking to get `action` value as VSCode shows a misleading value:

[VSCode showing misleading value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZG4.png)

I cannot manage to print only `action` value but the command `p t.transaction` outputs this (truncated) :

```
(ethcore_transaction::transaction::UnverifiedTransaction) $2 = {
unsigned = {
    action = Call(((20) ['\', '!', '\xf6', '\xff', '\x7f', '\0', ...])) {
    = Call(((20) ['\', '!', '\xf6', '\xff', '\x7f', '\0', ...])) {
        RUST$ENUM$DISR = Create {...}
```

In the case where `t.action = Action::Call()` the value is correctly shown.

Why does it not show `action = Create` ? How can I print more cleanly `action` value ?

EDIT: the command `fr v t->transaction.unsigned.action.RUST$ENUM$DISR` shows the correct enum value. However I still don't know why `fr v t->transaction.unsigned.action` displays wrong values (which are also shown in the graphical interface).

Comment: It looks like something is out of sync, and it is printing a different value than you intended. I'm not familiar with that debugging set up, but it could just be that you are debugging slightly different code than you are running.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem: when the enum is Call(Address) correct values are shown. I edited the post with new information.